# why everytime I convert to curve when I change shape from 3D to 2D I got weird result?

Tags: modeling

why everytime I convert to curve when I change shape from 2D->3D or 3D->2D I got weird result?
[image]

become like this: (straight line)
[image]

it moved into origin point with weird shape and not change even I change it back into 3D

NOTE: the curve is from edge (extrude vertices), and I convert it into curve.

Comment: Does it look like straight line if you rotate the view as well? Because if you make a curve 2D and your view is perpendicular to the plane of the curve, it will look like a line.

Comment: yes, I even I rotate the view, I already trying change to 2D shape in ortho-front-top view, but result is the curve changed into straight line..